# How can solve fetal error while adding action?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can remove fatal Error applying Following code
is controller.php

```
public function actionUser()
{
  $model= new UserForm();

    if($model->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {
        //lates Wirite later    
    }else{
        return $this->render('userForm',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

and UserForm models code:

```
class UserForm extends Model
{
public $name;
public $email;

public function rules()
{
     return[
            [['name','email'],'required'],
            ['email','email'],
            ];  

}
}
```

and views code:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

use yii\widgets\ActiveForms;

$form=ActiveForm::begin();

echo $form->field($model,'name');

echo $form->field($model,'email'); 

echo Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']);
```

[image]
    }

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Please include namespace declarations. I think you are missing the use statement.

Comment: just add `use app\models\UserForm; or path to UserForm` in controller

Comment: @InsaneSkull indeed, and also namespace in Model.

Comment: Thank you Insane Skull  now error occur on 'app\models\Model'

Comment: Use `namespace app\models;`  in `UserForm`.